# If a child has a certain specific value, how to check and make "true" so that hover of the parent yields a result?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Okay, the title is worded terribly, I know. I really don't know exactly how to describe this.

I am editing a "website" but I don't have access to HTML or Javascript or PHP or anything else. Only CSS, and I can creatively manipulate the HTML already presented in the website.

```
<div id="list">
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="td1">blahblahblah</td>
   <td class="td1">blahblahblah</td>
   <td class="td1">blahblahblah</td>
   <td class="td1"><a href="bleach.com">Bleach</td>
   <td class="td1">Score: 9</td>
  </tr>
 <tbody>
</table>

<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="td2">blahblahblah</td>
   <td class="td2">blahblahblah</td>
   <td class="td2">blahblahblah</td>
   <td class="td2"><a href="naruto.com">Naruto</a></td>
   <td class="td2">Score: 10</td>
  </tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

So this is basically how it's set up. These are 2 anime, Bleach and Naruto. Naruto's score is a 10, Bleach's is a 9. My goal is to select the parent table of the anime that contains a score of 10 so that I can set up a specific hover animation event using keyframes whenever an anime with a score of 10's table is hovered over.

Now the way this is set up, I don't think there's any way to do it other than manually selecting each anime with a score of 10 by doing something like #list > table > td:nth-of-type(4) a[href*="naruto.com"] though I'm not sure that's relevant. That's how I can select the child, but how do I select the table parent to style it for hover? There must be a way. :(

Appreciate any help you can offer. If you leave a comment within the next day I should be able to respond back immediately.

Thanks.

**Please keep in mind, I can not simply give a table a class or id. I have no access to adding or editing anything within the set HTML. So I need to figure out a different method. Also, selecting the table by doing #list table:nth-of-type(n) is not possible because the list of tables will be ever-changing (tables added/removed), can be sorted (altering n), and the sheer volume (we're talking hundreds of tables) etc. which would throw it out of play.**

Comment: You can't.  The "parent" or "ancestor" selector doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yes I know a parent selector doesn't exist currently, but I still think there must be a creative way to accomplish this.

Comment: @Dustin Perolio: There is not.

Comment: Well, thanks for trying. There is indeed no way to select the parent, which I already knew. I ended up figuring out a way to do as I wanted on my own though, thanks anyway guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using only CSS. You need to select for an attribute at least. There was a proposal for a `:content` selector for CSS 3, but that didn't end up in the spec. ([More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/css-3-content-selector)).

Answer (score 0):

My spirits were not dampened. I figured out a way to do it. By manipulating another td I don't need that's within the table that has a score of 10 and setting it to transparent and positioning it over the entire table, giving it a z-index of 1, and all of the other elements within the table a z-index of 2, I can cause the event on table hover to occur as I wished. :) I'm just posting this here in case anyone ever has a problem like this and this may help them as well.